# Prevent user returning from 'Qualified' Lead status value

Tags: formula, validation, leads, lead-conversion

Requirement: When users set lead to 'Qualified' I want validation to prevent them returning to any other status. I have tried the below but the validation kicks in when I am trying to convert because it is change status to 'Converted', preventing from converting

Any ideas?

CONTAINS( TEXT( PRIORVALUE( Status ) ) , "Qualified")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an exception for the *Converted* status to your validation rule:

```
AND( CONTAINS( TEXT( PRIORVALUE( Status ) ) , "Qualified" ),
TEXT( Status ) <> "Converted",
NOT( ISNEW( ) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you. Just noticed - when I use the above, I cannot create a lead with the value of Qualified. It just works when I change the value. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try my editted answer, we now also check whether the Lead is a new record using _NOT( ISNEW ( ) )_

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!